# hibernate multi-thread-multi-session and objects

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, session

Few facts regarding the setup:

- It's a Tomcat based app (althoug the issues arise outside Tomcat's context as well - JUNIT)
- Not using Spring
- Every thread has its own Hibernate `Session` (at TLS)
- Objects are being saved/loaded in a mixed way, i.e `ObjA` may be **created by thread A** and later be **manipulated by thread B** and even later be **updated by thread A** and yet again be **manipulated by thread Z but this time using HQL**!

Having the above setup I'm getting errors such as:

- `org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions`
- `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)`

My understanding is that

- It's all related to Hibernate's `Session`, being that a session "owns" the objects "attached" to it (those it created/loaded)
- AND POSSIBLY an issue of caching

The question is obvious:

- Am I understanding the core issue (above)?
- **How do I avoid such issues?**
- Is there a rule of thumb that would help avoid these issues?
- Would using Spring help solving it (be a bit specific about it please)?
- Would detaching from `Session` every object after fetching it from the datastore, and attaching it to a `Session` later just before updating it would be the ideal way to handle it?

I could of course avoid all of it if I'd use only one `Session` object but that sounds so... blocking (thread-wise).

I'm sure these sort of issues were solved long time ago, just need to find it (without re-inventing the wheel).

Comment: The second exception (StaleObjectStateException) is perfectly valid if you have multiple threads reading and writing the same DB entity concurrently, e.g. Thread 1 reads object A, thread 2 reads object A, thread 1 writes object A, thread 2 (attempts) to write object A - voila, exception.  Your code should handle this.

Comment: @JonoB right, my code should handle it, and that's about my question :) How do I handle it? I could come up with my own way I guess but I'm sure there are elegant ways to do so that someone here can share. The **how** is very important.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to read up about optimistic locking.

Comment: And yes, recovering from a `StaleObjectStateException` is one thing, but what about the other one (`....proxy with two open Sessions`)? This one is a killer, UNLESS I find some rule of thumb, like... don't even know!

Comment: It'd be good to see some code in the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `clear()` before fetching the object(s).

Answer (score 1):

The object is attached to a Hibernate session, yes. It can only be attached to one at a time, yes. Unless you close a Hibernate session, you could try to `evict()` the object, thus detaching it from the session, making it possible to load it in another thread. Problem is, that this may be unpractical, depending on your program flow.

Comment: Why would this may be unpractical? Please elaborate. I think I know..... Look, I fetch the objects. No lazy loading. Then, after some processing I call `saveOrUpdate()`. Now I think you can tell your opinion regarding this specific case :)

Comment: Well it depends on how your application works, I mean, how the threading works. Are they simple, terminating threads which just happen to work on the entities in an unpredictable, chaotic order, or are they endless looping threats, polling on the Database and getting them this way? In the latter case, eviction, saving and flushing might be a little bit too unpredictible.

I always felt unclean using eviction.. I'd rather really close the session and try to work on the rows in an ordered fassion.

Calling saveOrUpdate() and then evict() should work though.

Comment: I believe the threads access entities in an unpredictable manner, they are indeed in an endless loop polling on the datastore. When it finds a relevant entity it loads it, manipulates it and continue. In the meanwhile another thread might access the same entity.

Comment: Hm what about the Hibernate Optimistic Locking then? [Link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic)
It could save you from manually evicting entities and manage that all access attemps to the row are in order.